# How could I test customized object under lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Let's say I have a custom object put at /lib folder

I want to test it's functionality under Rspec, how could I do it ?

How could I create the test function ? where should it go ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
lib path is added in autoload path. if not, add `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

You have also spec directory `/spec`.
create lib directory `/spec/lib` and just create `{lib_test_name}_spec.rb`

and write code same as other spec.